# aligning horizontally using css

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<h2 >Floating box</h2>


</body>
</html>
```

Guys, I have this and I want to align the text with the box horizontally, how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to center align the floating-box then use  width:150px; margin:0 auto;

Comment: Please use the search next time, this question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.floating-box{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.floating-box-width-border {
    width: 150px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="floating-box floating-box-width-border">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box"><h2>Floating box</h2></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the "Floating Box" text inside that box.

```
.floating-box{
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you want to align the whole box horizontally relative to the body of the page.

```
.floating-box{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Or you could do both as per the following snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.floating-box {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<h2 >Floating box</h2>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to align the outside text (h2) with thw whole box horizontally

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. Could you provide a small illustration of what you're after? You want both items to be on the same line and aligned horizontally?